# Gdal: How to reproject from equirectangular to mercator?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, mercator

I work with raster ETOPO1, made a crop of my area of interest.

```
curl -L -C - 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip' -o ./ETOPO1.zip
unzip -n ./ETOPO1.zip '*.tif'
# --- crop
gdal_translate -projwin -5 51 10 41 ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif cropXL.tmp.tif
# --- resize for speed sake
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:4326 -te -5 41 10 51 -ts 1200 0 cropXL.tmp.tif resized.tmp.tif
# --- reproject into mercator
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 resized.tmp.tif resized-mercator.tif
```

But this result into an incorrect file. **What does I do wrong ? How to reproject correctly from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 ?**

**Note:** command inspired by [Re-project raster image from Mercator to Equirectangular](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92907/)

---

**Edit:**

```
yug@yug-PC:~/projects/WikiAtlas_scripts/back$ gdalinfo ./01_reliefs/crop_resized.tmp.tif -hist
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ./01_reliefs/crop_resized.tmp.tif
       ./01_reliefs/crop_resized.tmp.tif.aux.xml
Size is 1962, 1551
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (11365720.009993232786655,1654650.287315490888432)
Pixel Size = (323.425157454019200,-323.425157454019200)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=COARDS/CF-1.0
  NC_GLOBAL#GMT_version=4.4.0
  NC_GLOBAL#history=grdreformat ETOPO1_Ice_g_gdal.grd ETOPO1_Ice_g_gmt4.grd=ni
  NC_GLOBAL#node_offset=0
  NC_GLOBAL#title=ETOPO1_Ice_g_gmt4.grd
  x#actual_range=-180, 180
  x#long_name=Longitude
  x#units=degrees
  y#actual_range=-90, 90
  y#long_name=Latitude
  y#units=degrees
  z#_FillValue=-2147483648
  z#actual_range=-10898, 8271
  z#long_name=z
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (11365720.010, 1654650.287) (102d 6' 0.00"E, 14d42' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (11365720.010, 1153017.868) (102d 6' 0.00"E, 10d18' 6.40"N)
Upper Right (12000280.169, 1654650.287) (107d48' 1.26"E, 14d42' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (12000280.169, 1153017.868) (107d48' 1.26"E, 10d18' 6.40"N)
Center      (11683000.089, 1403834.078) (104d57' 0.63"E, 12d30'36.90"N)
Band 1 Block=1962x2 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.000 Max=0.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  1 buckets from 0 to 0:
  0 
  NoData Value=-2147483648
  Metadata:
    NETCDF_VARNAME=z
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
```

Comment: In what way the result is incorrect?

Comment: I expanded the post to the test is easily reproducible. I'am digging in to explain why it's incorrect. Basically, altitude is lost, i have a reprojected image which is all black in Qgis. Without data, I can't process it further.

Comment: Looks good on my QGIS. Check what options you use for rendering from Layer properties - Style. Play with contrast enhancement options - Stretch to MinMax is a good starting point. You can also check the histogram with `gdalinfo -hist`

Comment: I added my gdal info -hist for my file an other area of interest and other output name, but same process.

Comment: What is your GDAL version? I also suggest to run gdalinfo for each interim tiff you create. Statistics with zeros as min and max prove that your image is really all black. I sent my version as an answer because I want to encourage you with a screen capture.

Comment: @user30184: My metadata are very different from yours. I use `GDAL 1.11.0, released 2014/04/16`, and you ? I call my command from a makefile. It get late here, I will push on this tomorrow.

Comment: Version info is GDAL 2.0.0dev, released 2014/04/16 but it is a nightly build from the beginning of July. Installed from the Windows builds of gisinternals.com/sdk. But your BBOX is different also thus you can't have used the same commands which you report.

Comment: One thing, when you experiment with different extents and settings it is best to make sure that the old .tif.aux.xml file is deleted before a new run.

Comment: As a remark, ETOPO1 is 1/60 of degree, so when you resample to 1200 pixels widht, you actually INCREASE the size of your dataset. (60 * 15 = 900) I wouls use gdalwarp in one step, this would prevent NoData on the edges.

Comment: @user30184: About the bounding box: My script runs on 50 areas of interests with parameters such `gdal_translate -projwin $(WEST) $(NORTH) $(EAST) $(SOUTH)`, I myself checked the bug on the first area of my loop (Cambodia). For simplicity sake, I wrote you this question with a well known country in mind (`-projwin -5 51 10 41` = france). Since the BB changes for each of the 50 countries, resizing to 1200px make sense ... most of the times.

Comment: @user30184: Yet, the bug was occurring on all areas. I just noticed I was not deleting the `*.tif.aux.xml` files, I should indeed be more careful on this.

Comment: It does not seem to be critical to delete the .tif.aux.xml files but for sure a good practice. I tested that if the x.tif file is deleted but x.tif.aux.xml not and then a new x.tif file is created, then gdalinfo -stats reads data from the old and now invalid aux.xml file. I did not notice that QGIS is utilizing this wrong information, though.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the bug. I made to many changes since yesterday evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is odd, but by following exactly your workflow I get this as a result:

[image]

Gdalinfo with statistics for my version of resized-mercator.tif is here:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -556597.454, 6621293.723) (  5d 0' 0.00"W, 51d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  ( -556597.454, 5011872.466) (  5d 0' 0.00"W, 40d59'48.55"N)
Upper Right ( 1113920.713, 6621293.723) ( 10d 0'23.47"E, 51d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 1113920.713, 5011872.466) ( 10d 0'23.47"E, 40d59'48.55"N)
Center      (  278661.630, 5816583.095) (  2d30'11.74"E, 46d13'32.32"N)
Band 1 Block=1039x3 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray

     Metadata:
       NETCDF_VARNAME=z
       STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=3569
       STATISTICS_MEAN=34.570234537257
       STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-4953
       STATISTICS_STDDEV=1037.5075489272
```

Comment: Ok, I refactored my code to write down this question more clearly, I don't exactly know were was my error / trouble, I suspect the sequence of command (reproject then resize = bug, resize then reproject = ok), but it now works as you told me. Good !