# Using gdalwarp with multiple elevation models

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, srtm, gdal-translate

I'm trying to use `gdal_warp` to slice and convert some SRTM data. The data I'm interested in are in S30E152.hgt and S30E153.hgt. What I'd like to do is:

1. Convert these DEM files from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857
2. Select a subsection of the data at coordinates 17008000,-3590694  17051000,-3503623
3. Write this subsection to a GeoTIFF file for further processing

Firstly, I add the two DEM files to a VRT:

`gdalbuildvrt combined.vrt S30E152.hgt S30E153.hgt`

Then I check the VRT to ensure the height values are sane:

`gdalinfo -mm combined.vrt
[snip]
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
    Computed Min/Max=-14.000,1501.000
[snip]`

Then I use `gdal_warp` to convert and slice the VRT:

`gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te 17008000 -3590694 17051000 -3503623 -r bilinear combined.vrt sliced.tiff`

Then I check the GeoTIFF to ensure the height values are still sane:

`gdalinfo -mm sliced.tiff
[snip]
Band 1 Block=449x9 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,0.000
[snip]`

It appears that whenever I use `gdalwarp` with a VRT containing multiple DEMs, it always clobbers the height values. For comparison, I created a VRT with only a single DEM and tried the same operations (using a smaller subsection that fits within range).

`gdalbuildvrt test.vrt S30E152.hgt
gdalinfo -mm test.vrt  (produces Min/Max=-14.000,1501.000)
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te 16931600 -3388300 16976200 -3439400 -r bilinear test.vrt test.tiff
gdalinfo -mm test.tiff
[snip]
Band 1 Block=446x9 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=53.000,1471.000
[snip]`

This seems to work OK. Maybe the problem was with my coordinates. So I thought I'd warp the entire VRT, and then select the subsection:

`gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 combined.vrt converted.tiff
gdalinfo -mm converted.tiff
[snip]
Band 1 Block=2328x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=-14.000,1501.000
[snip]
gdaltranslate -projwin 17008000 -3503623 17051000 -3590694 converted.tiff sliced.tiff`

Although I've double-checked the coordinates, I always get this warning:

`Warning: Computed -srcwin 914 1337 449 910 falls partially outside raster extent. Going on however.`

Now this gives me a file with reasonable height values:

`gdalinfo -mm sliced.tiff
[snip]
Band 1 Block=449x9 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,369.000
[snip]`

However when I check to see if the data is sane, I get an empty image:

`gdal_translate -scale 0 369 0 255 -outsize 100 200 -of PNG sliced.tiff sliced.png`

At this point, I'm totally lost. I think I have data, but am not sure.

Comment: Forgot to add, `gdalwarp --version` reports `GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26`.

Comment: The question is OK. It contains all information which is needed for reproducing the case (except links to source DEMs). Nothing less in not enough for solving this case.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with my own DEM images and GDAL 2.0-dev. Without access to S30E152.hgt and S30E153.hgt I can't do more. However, there may be something odd with  gdalwarp and -te http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112395/gdal-how-to-reproject-from-equirectangular-to-mercator?noredirect=1#comment159010_112395. It would be nice to catch it.

Comment: @user30184 You should be able to get the data from the SRTM FTP site: http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Australia/

Comment: Convert the first .VRT into epsg:3857 and check the extents with gdalinfo. I get `Lower Left  (16920516.217,-3503628.939) Upper Right (17143287.264,-3375593.003)` It means that your slice with S coordinates between -3590694 and -3503623 do not hit the data.

Comment: Did you get it? `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te 17008000 -3490694 17051000 -3403623 -r bilinear combined.vrt sliced.tiff` work fine and gdalinfo -mm lists  Computed Min/Max=-11.000,536.000

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I added S31 DEM files to the VRT, warped the entire VRT and was able to select my subsection OK. Following your posted link, I then removed `*.aux.xml` and gdalwarp was able to reproject and slice the unprojected VRT in one operation OK (tested this time with `GDAL 1.9.0`). If you add your earlier comment as an answer, I'd accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally black output was a result from the extents which were used in the gdalwarp command. They were outside the image area and therefore the output was nothing else than nodata.

I recommend to use QGIS for debugging this kind of troubles. The VRT can be opened directly with QGIS as a raster layer and it can be reprojected on-the-fly to target projection which in this case was EPSG:3857. The target extents used as -te parameters can be placed on the QGIS map with the nice Quick WKT plugin. Convert `-te 17008000 -3590694 17051000 -3503623` into two WKT points or build a corresponding polygon from the corners as below:

```
POINT (17008000 -3590694)
POINT (17051000 -3503623)

POLYGON ((
        17008000 -3590694, 
        17008000 -3503623, 
        17051000 -3503623, 
        17051000 -3590694, 
        17008000 -3590694
    ))
```

Having a look at the QGIS map windows reveals immediately the reason for the empty gdalwarp output.

[image: DEM area and BBOX both in EPSG:3857]

It is also possible to clip and extract a slice of the DEM with QGIS by using the Clipper tool that is in menu Raster - Extraction - Clipper. However, if the VRT file combines hundreds or thousands of original images it is more efficient to use direct GDAL commands because opening such VRT into QGIS can be slow.